# .NET Thread unsafe code

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, thread-safety

I understand the difference between Multi Threaded Apartments and Single Threaded Apartments in COM.

Please see the code below:

```
'VB.NET
Imports Project1
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim t1 As New Thread(AddressOf PersonTest.Test2)
        Dim t2 As New Thread(AddressOf PersonTest.Test2)
        Dim t3 As New Thread(AddressOf PersonTest.Test2)
        t1.Name = "Test1"
        t2.Name = "Test2"
        t3.Name = "Test3"
        t1.Start()
        t2.Start()
        t3.Start()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class PersonTest
    Public Shared Sub Test2()
        Try
            Dim c1 As Class1
            c1 = New Class1
            For test3 As Integer = 0 To 10000
                For test As Integer = 0 To 10000
                    Dim test2 As Short = c1.Add(CShort(test))
                    If test2 <> test + 1 Then
                        MsgBox("Problem here")
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            MsgBox("finished")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Person
    Public id As Integer
End Class

'VB6 - Project1.vbp,class1
Public Test2 As Integer

Public Function Add(ByVal TestParameter As Integer) As Integer
Test2 = TestParameter + 1
Add = Test2
End Function
```

Based on what I have read, I would expect 'MsgBox("Problem here")' to appear because multiple threads could change the value of Person.ID out of sync, however I have tested this program a number of times and it has never happened.  I understand that "nothing is guaranteed" with threads.  Could the code above cause a problem in theory? If the answer is no, then how can the code be amended to cause a problem?  I am trying to learn how to write thread safe code and in order to do this I must first understand how code can be thread unsafe.

Comment: I assume you are calling it on multiple threads? I think the call to MsgBox has to be on the UI thread (not that it affects your threading issue)

Comment: @Rob, the code shows that three threads are created in the Form.Load handler function.

Comment: And the VB6 function 'Add' presumably that is inproc and not STA?

Comment: @SimonMourier Guessing a bit - but I assume it is what the VB6 class is called

Comment: If Class1 is Person, it's local to the thread (on its stack), so nothing is shared, so where should be the problem?

Comment: Without knowing what`Class1` is, there is nothing here being shared between the threads, so there are no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 generates COM components that are marked apartment threaded in the registry.  An expensive word for "not thread-safe".  The threads you created are in the MTA since you didn't call Thread.SetApartmentState().

First off, you are not actually testing code that's thread-unsafe, every thread gets its own object since you are allocating it as a local variable in the method.  Local variables are stored on the stack, every thread has its own stack.  Thread safety can only be compromised when more than one thread can both read and write to a shared variable.  You will have to create the object in the Form_Load() method and store the reference in a member of the form class to get sharing.

COM is not otherwise aware that you don't actually have a threading problem.  It will automatically start a *new thread*, one that's STA to give the COM object a safe home.  You can see those threads in the Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window.

And it automatically marshals the call to the Add() function from the worker thread to that STA thread.  As required by the apartment rules.  This is quite slow, your code should take a while.  Just as an experiment, call SetApartmentState for each thread before you start it to switch them to STA.  Now that helper thread is no longer required and no marshaling is needed, you'll see your code finishing a *lot* quicker.

Using a shared instance of Class1 will be a better test.  But updating the Test2 variable is still thread-safe since it is inside an apartment-threaded object.  The actual values it gets are however random, whatever thread last updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your problem seems to be that there isn't an oppertunity for multiple threads to update one value.

In each thread, you are creating a new instance of `Class1`, which has its own instance of `Test2`, so each of your threads is the only thread operating on it.

Changing your code to this will force it to exibit the problem you want, although I am not sure if this answers your question or not...

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim pt = New PersonTest

    Dim t1 As New Thread(AddressOf pt.Test2)
    Dim t2 As New Thread(AddressOf pt.Test2)
    Dim t3 As New Thread(AddressOf pt.Test2)
    t1.Name = "Test1"
    t2.Name = "Test2"
    t3.Name = "Test3"
    t1.Start()
    t2.Start()
    t3.Start()


End Sub


Public Class PersonTest

    Private _class As New Class1

    Public Sub Test2()
        Try

            For test3 As Integer = 0 To 10000
                For test As Integer = 0 To 10000

                    Dim test2 = _class.Add(test)
                    If test2 <> test + 1 Then
                        MsgBox("Problem here")
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            MsgBox("Finished")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Person
    Public id As Integer
End Class

Public Class Class1

    'VB6 - Project1.vbp,class1
    Public Test2 As Integer

    Public Function Add(ByVal TestParameter As Integer) As Integer
        Test2 = TestParameter + 1
        Add = Test2
    End Function

End Class
```